# Почему созданный login не обрабатывается logon-триггером?

Tags: sql, sql-server, триггер

Мне по заданию нужно создать два login'а в sql server: `op` и `another`.
Когда подключен `another`, `op` не может подключиться к серверу. Проблема только в том, что `op` либо вообще не обрабатывается триггером, либо обрабатывается неправильно и все равно подключается к серверу.

Вот так выглядит триггер:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я убираю условие `login_name = 'another'`, триггер работает (войти через `op` не удается, потому что подключен `another`). Но почему?? Я ведь зашел сначала под именем `another`, а потом под `op`, и вход под `op` оказался успешным. Почему не работал старый вариант? Может быть, я что-то неправильно понимаю и делаю?

Comment: Спутали `login_name` с `original_login_name`?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, нет, разницы нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил проблему. Вот исправленное тело триггера:

```
create trigger [connection_limit_TRG]
on all server with execute as 'sa'
for logon as
begin
    if ORIGINAL_LOGIN() = 'op' and 
       (select count(*) from sys.dm_exec_sessions a join sys.dm_exec_connections b
            on a.session_id = b.session_id
        where is_user_process = 1 and original_login_name = 'another') > 0
    begin
        rollback;
    end
end;
```

Стоит отметить, что при отсоединении сессии почему-то не закрываются, поэтому если вы столкнулись с такой проблемой, то их нужно закрыть вручную командой `kill`:

```
kill *session_id*
```

Список сессий (в моем случае для пользователя `another`) можно посмотреть с помощью следующего запроса:

```
select a.session_id, original_login_name 
from sys.dm_exec_sessions a join sys.dm_exec_connections b
            on a.session_id = b.session_id
        where is_user_process = 1 and original_login_name = 'another'
```

Если это не сработает, то, возможно, у вашего пользователя нет разрешения на просмотр статуса сервера. Разрешение можно выдать следующей командой:

```
grant view server state to my_login
```

my_login - логин, которому вы хотите выдать разрешение.